# Calling Mocha and piping results to string

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher, pipeline, mocha.js

I've created a a `FileSystemWatcher` object that I have events registered for. I intend that this script will run an execute `mocha` in the same directory. I can execute `mocha` from the script using:

```
$testProgram = "mocha"
& $testProgam
```

I get the results..
...

```
3 test complete....
```

Now when I take this same code and wrap it in the event like this...

```
$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
  clear
  write-host "Running Test Scripts.........."
  write-host "Changed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
  & testProgram
}
```

I get this...

```
Running Test Scripts.......................
Changed: C:\files\main.js
```

Where are the results of the `& testProgram`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PS to test this atm, so please correct me if I'm wrong. I can think of multiple problems that you could check out:

- You got a typo. In your action block, `testProgram` is missing a dollar-sign in front.
- I'm pretty sure that an ObjectEvent runs the action block in a seperate scope where you can't get the parameters from your script. You could try to use e.g. `$global:testProgram`.
- Relative paths may not work here. You might need absolute path to the "mocha" executable or what it is.

EDIT: I found a solution you can try for the possible scope-problem (reaching the `testprogram` variable inside your action block). Shay Levi posted this code sample on [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/07bbb0e5-0d31-451c-97e8-fad42361389f/). It uses the `-MessageData` parameter to pass input into your action-block. Here's his codesample:

```
#Use the -MessageData parameter:

Register-ObjectEvent ... -MessageData $foo

#Access the variable from within the action block

$event.MessageData
```